# Which parts of react-virtualized package I need?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-virtualized

I want to make infinite scroll page with image grid. Which parts of react-virtualized package I need? InfiniteLoader and WindowScroller and Masonry ? And how define limit of records in query when I scroll window.

Comment: what did you end up using to render images in masonry layout with infinite scroll

Answer (score 1):

`WindowScroller` works with the `Masonry` component but `InfiniteLoader` only works with `Grid` and `List`. ([The docs mention this.](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/InfiniteLoader.md#infiniteloader))

> And how define limit of records in query when I scroll window.

This question isn't really clear. Perhaps you should try something and then post a new question with what you've tried and why it isn't working.

Please be sure to read through and understand the [layout and animation constraints sections of the `Masonry` documentation](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Masonry.md#phase-2-layout) first though, to avoid any confusion. :)