# react-virtualized - InfiniteLoader with Masonry does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memoization, react-virtualized, windowing

I am using react-virtualized's example on Masonry ([here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/Masonry/Masonry.example.js))

And it works. But now I'm trying to add the InfiniteLoader to the example but I cannot get it to work.

Things I've tried:

- Not using WindowScroller and defining my own height

Initially I thought it would work by removing WindowScroller but the **loadMoreRows** callback is never called.

Also the **isRowLoaded** callback is never called aswell.

A piece of code that demonstrates how it is:

```
<InfiniteLoader
  isRowLoaded={this._isRowLoaded}
  loadMoreRows={this._loadMoreRows}
  rowCount={myList.length}
>
  {({ onRowsRendered, isScrolling, registerChild }) => (
    <WindowScroller overscanByPixels={OVERSCAN}>
      {this._renderAutoSizer}
    </WindowScroller>
  )}
</InfiniteLoader>
```

From the **_renderAutoSizer** it is just like the example. No changes. The Masonry works as expected but cannot implement infinite scrolling.

I understand that I need to use onRowsRendered somehow. But the examples show usage with Lists and Grids. Masonry has no way of connecting with InfiniteLoader it seems.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `onCellsRendered` Masonry method

> Callback invoked with information about the cells that were most recently rendered. This callback is only invoked when visible cells have changed: ({ startIndex: number, stopIndex: number }): void
>   [more here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Masonry.md)

and check if `stopIndex === (myList.length - 1)` and has more items then invoke a method to loading more items.

Comment: Yes, but instead of checking for last item, check for `stopIndex >= Math.floor(myList.length - 1 - (limit / 2))` in order to fetch more once you've at least rendered half of the new page. The only problem here is that you'd need to keep track of loaded pages and in-flight requests to avoid double requests.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198921/which-parts-of-react-virtualized-package-i-need) InfiniteLoader only works with `Table`, `List` and `Grid`. [InfiniteLoader docs](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/InfiniteLoader.md#infiniteloader):

> Note that this component is intended to assist with row-loading. As such it is  best suited for use with `Table` and `List` (although it can also be used with `Grid`). This component is not compatible with the `Collection` component.